Need connector ideas
I am designing a transducer with two platinum electrodes (black lines in below picture).
These electrodes are going into acrylic discs above it (blue boxes), 20mm Outer Diameter, 15mm Inner Diameter, 2-5mm thick. Currents are not much, like 10mA.
From those acrylic disks there are connected to copper wires (Red lines).
I need ideas of how to make the copper wires enter the disks. Any suitable small connectors?
I thought of gland connectors, but the disk thickness is maybe only few millimetres and no gland would be small enough. And I'd like it to be plug‑and‑attach/detach style arrangement.
We can also make it permanent so please suggest how to do that, too. I thought of filling in the disk with some solidifying resin, but that seems crude.
Edit 1: I was thinking of 2 pin magnetic connectors, but they are way too expensive.


Spontaneously it sounds like some manner of flat flex cable could be suitable. But there's way too little info still. We don't understand the application nor the requirements nor the project/product budget so we can't sensibly help you picking a connector either.

I suggest a "parallel mate" connector because it includes the 90 degree bend that you need inside the disk. Ideally, you would have a tiny disk-shaped PCB inside the acrylic disk onto which the parallel mate PCB header would be soldered.

{Source GradConn}
These wire-to-board connectors are made by a few companies. For example, the Molex Pico-EZmate.
I made a list of 15 parallel mate connectors.

@Iskander said (in a deleted comment) : I think this is the best option.
